# How to disable a link?

Tags: html, css

I have a link tag, but I would like to make it inactive by CSS. I was trying to do it but only works in Mozilla. Here is my CSS style.

```
.inactive-link{
   pointer-events: none !important;
   cursor: default !important;
}
```

I just want to do it by CSS not by javascript. Thanks

Comment: what version of IE have you tested on? looks like IE 10+ supports `pointer-events`.

Comment: I was trying also in IE 10.

Comment: Definitely doesnt work in IE any version!

Comment: If you want jQuery solution `$('.inactive-link').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: @mdesdev wow, I've tested and it did not work. It should not work because the `user-select` is designed to control the ability of *selection*. I **couldn't** understand why you could left that comment, a useless comment. If it works, go ahead and post your own answer. sounds easy? BTW **who** upvoted the comment of ***mdesdev***? please join in the discussion.

Comment: Have you checked what compatability mode you're running within IE 10? This seems to work for me using CSS. I also found a CodePen that is an example of doing this which seems to work well: http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/yxboB

Comment: Liam in IE 10 doesnt work, document mode 10 and user agent string 10 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no perfect way to disable a link using CSS.

Using CSS what you can do is the following:

```
a
{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

This you have used already. And this won't be supported by IE.

**The best thing that you can do is make use of script.There is no perfect way to disable a link using pure CSS. You can achieve this using script in many ways.**